# How to write tensor product in terms of normal addition and mulitplication?

Tags: tensor-products

Im struggling to understand tensor product since there seems to be no way of wrting them as some combination of simple addition and multiplication. In the case of dot and cross product, such representation makes things a lot easier. so can we write tensor product in such a way. If not, why?

Answer (score 4):

In view of your comment on the answer from AOrtiz, I'm guessing that the question was intended to be about expressing the components of a simple tensor $v\otimes w$ in terms of the components of $v$ and of $w$. For that purpose, it is necessary to observe first that, if $V$ and $W$ have dimensions $m$ and $n$, then $V\otimes W$ has dimension $mn$. In more detail if the components of $v$ are $v_i$ ($1\leq i\leq m$) and the components of $w$ are $w_\alpha$ ($1\leq\alpha\leq n$), then the components of $v\otimes w$ are indexed by pairs $(i,\alpha)$. In those terms, there's a very simple formula: The $(i,\alpha)$-component of $v\otimes w$ is just the product $v_iw_\alpha$.

Comment: And you can picture it with matrices too: $vw^\top = (v_iw_j)_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It is very challenging to give a precise description of what a tensor product is if you have never heard of vector spaces or know what a bilinear function is. Loosely speaking, the tensor product $T$ of two vector spaces is itself another vector space. $T$ is spanned by elements of the form $v\otimes w$. It is impossible to be more precise about what the elements $v\otimes w$ actually "are" without appealing to quotient spaces and the actual construction of $T$ from two simpler vector spaces.

Assuming you know what a bilinear function is, you can give another description of $v\otimes w$: given a bilinear map $B:V\times W\to L$, $v\otimes w$ is *the* element that is mapped by the function $\Phi:T\to L$ guaranteed in the *universal property* of the tensor product  to $B(v,w)$.

Again, these words won't make much sense unless you are already comfortable with vector spaces and bilinear functions.

---

The tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $F$ is a *vector space* $V\otimes_F W$ whose elements are sums of so-called "simple tensors" of the form $v\otimes w$. On the other hand, the cross and dot products are examples of *functions* defined on Euclidean spaces.

The distinction is that the tensor product is not an operation on a vector space whereas the dot and cross products are.

Comment: Im sorry but these words confuse the hell out of me ( as every textbook ever). so first, is there an explanation using simpler words? Secondly, whats's explicit representation of the v tensor w, by that I mean can we write the result that looks like a vector or something ?

Comment: @Zeyuan You should try to gain a mastery of vector spaces and bilinear functions before you really try hard to understand what a tensor product is, but if you insist, here is a blog entry on tensor products that does a good job explaining it: https://jeremykun.com/2014/01/17/how-to-conquer-tensorphobia/

Comment: @Zeyuan It sounds like you are trying to put the cart before the horse, i.e. do the equivalent of learning calculus before learning middle school algebra. Maybe vector spaces and bilinear functions don't sound as sexy to you as tensors, but everything has its place, and it really isn't much of a stretch to say that the place of tensors is _after_ that of vector spaces and bilinear functions.

Comment: a question on bilinear map: whats so special about it. I mean, how does it differ from the linear transformation in my linear algebra class? If I take the cartesian product of R and R, I just get R^2, and the map from R^2 to some vector space is just a ordinary linear transformation. So why not write V X W as a single vector space which would make my life a hell lot easieer

Comment: @Zeyuan Bilinear maps $f:V\times W\to L$ are in general not linear. They have the important property that they are linear when restricted to either component. Their significance is that given any bilinear map $B:V\times W\to L$, there is a unique linear map $\Phi$ from the tensor product $V\otimes W\to L$ such that $\Phi(v\otimes w) = B(v,w)$.

Comment: but I always thought that cartesian product is just attach things at the end. for example, (1,0) X (0,1) is just (1,0,0,1) which is a vector in R^4. why the hell do we want to write R^2 X R^2, not just R^4. Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: also, I always see expressions like e1 tensor e2 and I have no idea what they looks like. If we take R^2 tensor R^3, isnt e1 tensor e2 just (1,0,0,1,0)?

Comment: The spaces $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^4$ are isomorphic, not equal. The isomorphism is $((x,y),(z,w))\mapsto (x,y,z,w)$. All these parenthesis are *not* unnecessary, try to understand why. In $\Bbb R^2 \otimes \Bbb R^2$, you can see $e_1\otimes e_2$ as a map $(\Bbb R^2)^* \times (\Bbb R^2)^*\to \Bbb R$ defined by $e_1\otimes e_2(f,g) = f(e_1)g(e_2)$. But you ought to get used to bilinear maps first, it will make your life easier up ahead.

Comment: @Zeyuan, Also $\mathbb R^2\otimes\mathbb R^3$ is a $2\times 3 = 6$-dimensional vector space, illustrating further how the tensor product is not the same as the direct or Cartesian product of two vector spaces.

Comment: so another question: how do we write basis of R2 tensor R3 in simple "numbers in brackets", without all those fancy tensor fluff?

Comment: @Zeyuan It depends on what you mean. As *vector spaces*, $\mathbb R^2\otimes \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^6$ are isomorphic, so in a sense you have a way to write them down with $6$ coordinates, but that would really defeat the purpose of why you are interested in the tensor product. The tensor product really ought to be seen as the vector space with the universal property I described above. That is the main purpose it serves. In general, the tensor product is best understood in terms of how it interacts with other vector spaces, not really so much in terms of what *it* is.

Comment: Im thinking that what makes tensor product so mysterious is that there seems to be no way of expressing them in notation im familiar with. Basically what I've been trying to do in all those comments is finding a way to represent what you guys have been saying, which is very helpful by the way, using notations that Im confortable with. However, every time I come up with an idea, you say its wrong and I can see that. But whats the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Zeyuan I would say that the right way of learning about tensor products would be to first understand bilinear maps. Then learn about quotient spaces. Then read that blog post I shared with you.

Comment: no, I dont mean the right way of learning tensor product

Comment: I mean how do you explain this using notations that are typically used in a first semester linear algebra class, is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61584/discussion-between-zeyuan-and-aortiz).

Answer (score 0):

A much simplified working definition that may assist you:

Consider a finite $n$-tensor as a grid of values indexed by $n$ natural numbers. For example, a $2\times3\times2$ 3-tensor $t$ might have $1.5$ at $(2,1,1)$, in which case we'd write $$t(2,1,1) = 1.5$$
In this simple paradigm, consider an example tensor product between $p_{ace}$ (a $2\times 3\times 5$ 3-tensor), $t_{ab}$ (a $2\times 8$ 2-tensor), and $q_{cef}$ (a $3\times 5\times 2$ 3-tensor), that is $$p_{ace} t_{ab} q_{cef}$$
Find all the repeated indices, which happen to be $a,c,e$.

Find all the non-repeated indices, which are $b,f$.

Then the product is a tensor indexed by the non-repeated indices, and each of its elements is the sum of of all products over the repeated indices.

Hence if $$s_{bf} = p_{ace} t_{ab} q_{cef}$$ then $$s(b,f) = \sum _{a = 1}^{2}\sum _{c = 1}^{3} \sum _{e = 1}^{5} p(a,c,e)\cdot t(a,b)\cdot q(c,e,f)\;\;\forall b = 1\ldots 8, \; f = 1\ldots 2$$

If you consider an $r\times c$ matrix to be a 2-tensor $M_{rc}$, then the matrix product $C = AB$ you know and love is simply $$C_{ac} = A_{ab}B_{bc}$$ or equivalently $$C(a,c) = \sum _{b} A(a,b)\cdot B(b,c)\;\;\forall\; a,c$$

Hopefully this helps.